# Change mouse scroll direction with hammerspoon

Tags: macos, lua, hammerspoon

Is there a way to change the mouse scroll direction with hammerspoon?
I would like to change the direction with a Shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

As of November 2019 it doesn't seem available.

You can retrieve the current scroll direction with `hs.mouse.scrollDirection()` ([Hammerspoon docs](https://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/hs.mouse.html#scrollDirection)) but no function allows to set it.